# Fullpage.js when resize scrollOverflow create bug page view goes to bottom

Tags: jquery, scroll, resize, responsive, fullpage.js

I recently began using fullPage.js for a project and I have a issue: 
If I use scrollOverflow: true when I resize browser page goes to bottom

This is my code:

```
        scrollingSpeed: 800,
        autoScrolling: homeAutoScrolling,
        fitToSection: false,
        fitToSectionDelay: 1000,
        scrollBar: true,
        ...
        offsetSections: true,
        scrollOverflow: true,
        scrollOverflowReset: false,
        scrollOverflowOptions: {
          scrollbars: false,
          mouseWheel: true,
          hideScrollbars: true,
          fadeScrollbars: false
        },
        touchSensitivity: 15,
        normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 5,
        animateAnchor: true,
        recordHistory: false,
        controlArrows: true,
        verticalCentered: true,
        sectionSelector: '.full-screen',
        slideSelector: '.full-screen',
        lazyLoading: true,

        onLeave: function (index, nextIndex, direction) {},
        afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {},
        afterRender: function () {},
        afterResize: function () {},
        afterResponsive: function (isResponsive) {},
        afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {},
        onSlideLeave: function (anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex) {}
      })
    }
```

If I use scrollOverflow: false when resize everything ok but I need scrollOverflow: true to able scroll in sections have long content.

Is there anything else I'm missing here to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide an isolated reproduction of the issue in codepen or jsfiddle?
The [demo page](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html) seems to be working fine?

Comment: I using fullpage.js with WordPress so I can't reproduction of the issue in codepen or jsfiddle :(

Comment: One can always create isolated reproductions :)
If the issue is not in Wordpress, but in fullPage.js, then wordpress is not necessary for the reproduction.